# When accessing Properties, send to another instance

Tags: python

```
class x():
    def __init__(self):
        self.z=2

class hi():
    def __init__(self):
        self.child=x()

f=hi()
print f.z
```

I want it to print `2`.

Basically I want to forward any calls to that class to another class.

Comment: This is called the proxy pattern. Why do you need it? It's not very elegant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest approach is implementing [`__getattr__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__):

```
class hi():
    def __init__(self):
        self.child=x()

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.child, attr)
```

This has certain disadvantages, but it might work for your limited use case. You might want to implement `__hasattr__` and `__setattr__` as well.

Comment: Can the __ of '__child' hurts when inheriting from hi? When does the double underscore become an issue when inheriting?

Comment: Wait, wat? Name mangling has nothing to do with `__getattr__`, it simply replaces any occurence of `__foo` in the class definition with `_ClassName__foo`. (And by the way, the whole point of that is avoiding name collisions with subclasses.) Independently of that, `__getattr__` is only called if an attribute does not exist -- you code still works if you remove one or both underscores.

Comment: @delnan: Well, in that case it's really useless, I had it in the back of my head somehow :) As for the name mangling part, I was mainly referring to the issue regarding inheritance (because in my experience, it's rarely necessary)

Answer (score 0):

The Python syntax is:

```
class hi(x):
```

To say that `hi` inherit (should be a child of) `x`.

.

*Note: in order for `hi` to have property `z` (since this is in `hi`'s `__init__`) `x.__init__` needs to be explicitly run in `x`. That is,*

```
class hi(x):
    def __init__(self):
        x.__init__(self)
```

Comment: As I understand it, OP wants something like the proxy pattern